# Помогите решить задачу про пирожные

Tags: python

Для праздничного чаепития необходимо купить n пирожных. В магазине продается всего два вида пирожных, причем пирожных одного вида осталось a штук, а пирожных другого вида осталось b штук. Пирожные одного вида считаются одинаковыми. Сколькими способами можно купить ровно n пирожных?

**Входные данные**

В первой строке входных данных записано число n — количество пирожных, которое нужно купить, во второй и третьей строке записаны числа a и b — количество пирожных каждого из двух видов, которые есть в магазине. Все числа — целые, от 1 до 100.

**Выходные данные**

Программа должна вывести одно целое число — количество различных способов купить n пирожных.

**Примеры**

Ввод

5
3
10

Вывод

4

**Примечание**

В примере из условия купить 5 пирожных можно 4 способами: 0 пирожных первого вида и 5 пирожных второго вида, 1 пирожное первого вида и 4 пирожных второго вида, 2 пирожных первого вида и 3 пирожных второго вида, 3 пирожных первого вида и 2 пирожное второго вида. Больше способов нет, так как в магазине есть только 3 пирожных первого вида.

Пробовал решить, но появляется ошибка

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(max(0, min(a, b) - max(0, n-b) + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Если a+b< n, 0
2. Если a+b>=n

   1. a< n, b< n a+b-n+1
   2. a< n, b>=n a+1
   3. a>=n, b< n b+1
   4. a>=n, b>=n n+1

Программа

```
n,a,b=map(int,input().split())

if a+b<n:
    print('0')
else:
    if a<n and b<n:
        print(a+b-n+1)
    if a<n and b>=n:
        print(a+1)
    if a>=n and b<n:
        print(b+1)
    if a>=n and b>=n:
        print(n+1)
```

Comment: а я думал тут import collections будет

Comment: @eri можно, но нет смысла. Поскольку все шары одинаковые, то их количество относительно n определяет решение